# Make/Import Image Slider ASP.NET in Aspx Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, slider

I want to make a website and in the Home Page `Home.aspx` I want to have an ImageSlider.

I want the ImageSlider to get his URLs from my database. I made a function which connects to my database and returns my images Array.

This is my `Home.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_Home" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <asp:Image ID="sliderImageNews" runat="server" style="height:400px; width:100%; "/>

</asp:Content>
```

I wanted to put a timer and in each interval to change the ImageUrl but it calls `Page_Load` every time..

I would like something like this slider from Microsoft Website : 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us

How should i start ? Or what pieces of advice can you tell me?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery Sliders instead of creating your own, And bind the image urls as per the slider type

http://designscrazed.org/free-responsive-jquery-image-sliders/

Comment: and after i download one , what to do next? i am a beginner, sorry :D

Comment: Here is the the link with asp.net example.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Image-Slider-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx